# A Limits Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

Using the fact that $$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(h)}{h} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\cos(h)-1}{h}=0\text{,}$$
Compute the following limits:

- $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$
- $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)}{h}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $\color{blue}{\sin (x+h)=\sin x\cos h+\cos x\sin h}$ it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (x+h)-\sin x}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin x\cos h+\cos x\sin h-\sin x}{h}\\
&=\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}\right)\sin x+\cos x\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}\right)
\end{align}

For the another one you may use $\color{blue}{\cos(x+h)=\cos x\cos h-\sin x\sin h}$.

Comment: So for the first one, I have sin(x)*0+cos(x)*1. Is that the answer or is there some constant that it can be simplified down to, (I know the sin(x)*0 goes away). So I am left with just cos(x). Is that the answer and is -sin(x) the answer to the second one or can they be simplified?

Comment: @Zachary You are right: $\cos (x)$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it turns out that by the angle sum rules $\sin(x + h) = \sin x \cos h + \cos x \sin h.$ The rest is just pulling stuff that doesn't depend on $h$ out of the limit and using the two given identities.

Comment: How do you pull stuff out of the limit?

Comment: @Zachary Remember that $\sin x$ is just a number from the perspective of $\lim_{h\to0}$. That's because $x$ isn't varying with $h$ so we just choose some number, call it $x$, plug it into our calculator and hit the $\sin$ key, and get that number $\sin x$ out of it. In general $\lim_{h\to0} f(x) g(h) = f(x) \lim_{h\to0} g(h)$ for this reason. You can prove it with the delta-epsilon definition of limit if you want, but it's not that complicated of an idea if you just express it out.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much :).